# SSD doesn't appear in My Computer

Tags: windows-8, ssd, dell-inspiron

I just bought a new Dell laptop. It is an Inspiron 14z 5423 with i7, 500GB HD, and 32GB SSD.

I cannot find the SSD in "My Computer".

**Why isn't the SSD being displayed, and how can I be sure it's present?**

Comment: Please right-click *Computer*, choose *Manage*, then *Disk management* and tell us what you see (or better post a screenshot).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SSD is an m-SATA caching device and NOT a separate storage device.  It caches the spinning platter hard drive and after several observations of your habits, caches the most used data and sends it to your CPU instead of waiting for the slower spinning platter to do it.

Dell's support site has a manual that indicates that the m-SATA is buried.  You have to remove the RAM, optical drive, palm rest, battery...  you have to disassemble the system to see it.

Comment: thank you for the answer... do you have the link for the Dell's manual that explains this thing?

Comment: ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_inspiron_laptop/inspiron-14z-5423_Owner%27s%20Manual_en-us.pdf